# SSL certificate installation with p7b and cer file in redhat server

Tags: https, linux

I have issue with applying SSL certificate, I already transfer my csr and key on **/etc/pki/tls/private** and I have **.p7b** and **cer** file may I know what I need to do with these files to apply the SSL certificate on my server with redhat OS?

If you have steps or guide it would be great help for me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using Apache, Nginx, or some other web server software?

Comment: Hi @StephenOstermiller, I'm using Apache (httpd)